# Method .GetType() returns different values for the same variable

Tags: powershell, function, methods

Practicing with the . GetType() method, I have found that if I write a function that returns 'Name' and 'BaseType' I get a different result than expected when I do not write the function.

Example:

```
function Get-BaseType_Name {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ValuefromPipeline=$True)]
        [System.Object]$var   
    )
    $var.GetType() | Select -Property Name, BaseType;
} 
$var = Get-Service
$var | Get-BaseType_Name
```

I get:

```
Name              BaseType                       
----              --------                       
ServiceController System.ComponentModel.Component
```

However, if I execute the sentences:

```
$var = Get-Service
$var.GetType() | Select -Property Name, BaseType;
```

I get:

```
Name              BaseType                       
----              --------                       
Object[]          System.Array
```

Why is that?

I expected the same result in both cases

Comment: PS when only one item is return doesn't make it an array.  Solution is to force an array by adding `@(....)` around the object.  In your case you want type of first item so you can use : ((@($var))[0]).GetType()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @MatthiasRJessen's answer, you're passing service objects into your function one-at-a-time via the pipeline.

There's a *little* bit more to it though - the reason you're only seeing one output result is because your function is equivalent this:

```
function Get-BaseType_Name {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ValuefromPipeline=$True)]
        [System.Object]$var
    )
    END {
    #^^^^ END BLOCK
        $var.GetType() | Select -Property Name, BaseType;
    }
}
```

That is, your function body is being treated as an `end` block, which you can confirm if you look at the AST that PowerShell generates for your code:

```
${function:Get-BaseType_Name}.Ast.Body
```

which produces the following output.

(Note that the `BeginBlock` and `ProcessBlock` are empty and your code appears in the `EndBlock`).

```
Attributes         : {}
UsingStatements    : {}
ParamBlock         : param(
                             [Parameter(Mandatory,ValuefromPipeline=$True)]
                             [System.Object]$var
                         )
BeginBlock         :
^^^^^^^^^^ no definition

ProcessBlock       :
^^^^^^^^^^^^ no definition

EndBlock           : param(
                             [Parameter(Mandatory,ValuefromPipeline=$True)]
                             [System.Object]$var
                         )
                         $var.GetType() | Select -Property Name, BaseType
^^^^^^^^ your code is in this block

DynamicParamBlock  :
ScriptRequirements :
Extent             : {
                         param(
                             [Parameter(Mandatory,ValuefromPipeline=$True)]
                             [System.Object]$var
                         )
                         $var.GetType() | Select -Property Name, BaseType;
                     }
Parent             : function Get-BaseType_Name {
                         param(
                             [Parameter(Mandatory,ValuefromPipeline=$True)]
                             [System.Object]$var
                         )
                         $var.GetType() | Select -Property Name, BaseType;
                     }
```

If you have a look at the [`end`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-7.3#end) section in [`about_Functions_Advanced_Methods`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-7.3) it says:

> **end**
>
> This block is used to provide optional one-time post-processing for the function.

What's happening is PowerShell is feeding each of the results from `Get-Service` into the `Get-BaseType_Name` function one-at-a-time, but your code is only actually doing anything once the *last* item has been processed, and in that case `$var` holds a reference to the last item, which you can see if you run this instead:

```
function Get-BaseType_Name {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ValuefromPipeline=$True)]
        [System.Object]$var
    )
    write-host $var.Name
    #^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -- write the name of the service to the console
    $var.GetType() | Select -Property Name, BaseType;
}

Get-Service | Get-BaseType_Name
```

On my machine I see this output:

```
XboxNetApiSvc

Name              BaseType
----              --------
ServiceController System.ComponentModel.Component
```

where `XboxNetApiSvc` is the name of the last service returned by `Get-Service`.

If you want to see the output for **every** item you can put your code in the `process` block instead:

```
function Get-BaseType_Name {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ValuefromPipeline=$True)]
        [System.Object]$var
    )
    PROCESS {
    #^^^^^^^^ PROCESS BLOCK
        $var.GetType() | Select -Property Name, BaseType;
    }
}

Get-Service | Get-BaseType_Name
```

and then your optput will look like this:

```
Name              BaseType
----              --------
ServiceController System.ComponentModel.Component
ServiceController System.ComponentModel.Component
ServiceController System.ComponentModel.Component
... etc ...
```

In summary, you're sending a collection of service through the pipeline (per @MathiasRJessen's answer), but you're only returning values for the **last** item in that collection because PowerShell is implicitly treating your function body as an `end` block...

Answer (score 1):

From the [`about_Pipelines` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-7.3#one-at-a-time-processing):

> ### One-at-a-time processing
>
> [...]
>
> When you pipe multiple objects to a command, **PowerShell sends the objects to the command one at a time**. When you use a command parameter, the objects are sent as a single array object. This minor difference has significant consequences.
>
> When executing a pipeline, **PowerShell automatically enumerates any type that implements the `IEnumerable` interface** and sends the members through the pipeline one at a time. The exception is [hashtable], which requires a call to the GetEnumerator() method.

In other words: this is by design - PowerShell sees that `$var`  contains an array (a type that implements the `IEnumerable` interface), and starts enumerating the items in it one-by-one

You can prevent automatic enumeration by using `Write-Output -NoEnumerate`:

```
PS ~> Write-Output $var -NoEnumerate | Get-BaseType_Name

Name              BaseType                       
----              --------                       
Object[]          System.Array
```